# Error "outcome is not defined" in JSF navigation

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I am trying to learn JSF but not able to navigate from one page to another:

My faces config.xml is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>hello1</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>hello.Hello</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>
 <navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>index.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-action>#{hello.getworld}</from-action>
        <from-outcome>root</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>1.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
        </navigation-rule>  
</faces-config>
```

Hello bean is below:

```
package hello;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

@ManagedBean
public class Hello {

    final String world = "root";

    public String getworld() {
        return world;
    }
}
```

It's saying "outcome is not defined". I don't know how to navigate properly.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Implicit Navigation in JSF](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/implicit-navigation-in-jsf-2-0/) from mkyong. I think there you will find your answer.

If you want further information to get into JSF-Naviagtion try out the following link: [JSF - Page Navigation](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsf/jsf_page_navigation.htm)

Do not hesitate to leave a comment, if anything is not clear.

Comment: Your bean name is hello1 while in navigation you have used hello.